# AlertDialog setTitle() and setMessage equivalents in FragmentDialog

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-fragments

I'm rewriting an existing app for Honeycomb and I've run into a problem. In the existing app, we create the an AlertDialog with default title and message values, then replace them later if needed. To replace them, we use setTitle() and setMessage():

```
AlertDialog dialog = getDialog();
if (some condition) {
    dialog.setTitle(R.string.error1);
    dialog.setMessage(getResources().getString(R.string.error1_msg));
}
else {
    dialog.setTitle(R.string.error2);
    dialog.setMessage(getResources().getString(R.string.error2_msg));
}
```

However, now that we are using DialogFragment, there is no method for setTitle() or setMessage(), so we can't change it after it has been created. Is there a workaround for this case, or are we out of luck?

Comment: I wonder if you will have to extend DialogFragment and write your own accessor methods. Will check back to see what people say.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to extend the DialogFragment to provide content. See the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html) for examples and other options.

Comment: I have extended DialogFragment, but the DialogFragment class doesn't have any way of setting the Title or Message outside of onCreateDialog()

Comment: If I create an accessor method in my Fragment that extends DialogFragment, I can set the title, but there is no way to set the message. Unfortunately, I think this is a limitation of DialogFragments. I haven't been able to find a work around.

Comment: I was able to do it in the class that extends DialogFragment.
`public void setTitle(int title) {`
    `getDialog().setTitle(title);`
`}`
  
`public void setMessage(CharSequence message) {`
    `((AlertDialog)getDialog()).setMessage(message);`
`}`

Comment: Glad you solved. Ya you can add whatever methods you need to update content on the dialog fragment.